# Add a custom help message at the end of --help screen with clap-derive

Tags: rust, clap

Using Rust's [Clap](https://github.com/clap-rs/clap) crate, I would like to add a message at the bottom of the help screen (after all the flag description). Is there a way to do it with the `clap-derive`?

```rust
#[derive(Parser, Debug, Default)]
#[command(about, version)]
pub struct Args {
    /// Path to a file.
    #[arg(short, long)]
    pub file: Option<PathBuf>,
}
```

Expected output:

```
MyProgram ...

  --file FILE  Path to a file

Some very long explanation that should be printed at the end of the help screen
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the [`after_help` property](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/struct.Command.html#method.after_help)

```rust
#[derive(Parser, Debug, Default)]
#[command(about, version, after_help = 
    "Some very long explanation that should be printed at the end of the help screen"
)]
pub struct Args {
    /// Path to a file.
    #[arg(short, long)]
    pub file: Option<PathBuf>,
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bffa7482ab66502dd195bfd8449208c9)